# UIImageView Alignment

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIImageView in a tableviewcell and have the content mode set to scaleAspectFill:

```
let imageSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
MenuImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

if(self.reuseIdentifier == "cell1") {
    MenuImage.image = UIImage.imageWithIonicon(.Map, color: UIColor.white, iconSize: 70, imageSize: imageSize)
}
else if (self.reuseIdentifier == "cell2") {
    MenuImage.image = UIImage.imageWithIonicon(.iOSPerson, color: UIColor.white, iconSize: 70, imageSize: imageSize)

}
else if (self.reuseIdentifier == "cell3") {
    MenuImage.image = UIImage.imageWithIonicon(.iOSHelp, color: UIColor.white, iconSize: 70, imageSize: imageSize)
}
```

Although this fits the image nicely to the cell, the image appears to align to the bottom.  Is there a way to get it to centre vertically within the UIImageView (the brown background is just so I can check the size of the image view)

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `.scaleAspectFit`?

Comment: both seem to produce similar results (aligned to the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [This](https://github.com/tomsterritt/IoniconsSwift/commit/70f94cbeb501fa174a638e7a0b825192854c6eab) in order to fix vertical alignment, in your "ionicons.swift" file you need to change this line:

```
attString.drawInRect(CGRect(x: (imageSize.width / 2) - boundingRect.size.width / 2, y: (imageSize.height / 2) - boundingRect.size.height / 2, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
```

to

```
attString.drawInRect(CGRect(x: (imageSize.width / 2) - (boundingRect.size.width / 2), y: (imageSize.height / 2) - (iconSize / 2), width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
```

*Swift 3.0 version, replace this:

```
attString.draw(in: CGRect(x: (imageSize.width / 2) - boundingRect.size.width / 2, y: (imageSize.height / 2) - boundingRect.size.height / 2, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
```

with

```
attString.draw(in: CGRect(x: (imageSize.width / 2) - (boundingRect.size.width / 2), y: (imageSize.height / 2) - (iconSize / 2), width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. didn't even think about it being an issue with IocIcons

Answer (score 1):

This is an example about constraints and anchors:

```
self.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.addSubview(yourImageView)

containerView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomAnchor).active=true
containerView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leftAnchor).active=true

yourImageView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.topAnchor).active=true
yourImageView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.leftAnchor).active=true
yourImageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(70).active=true
yourImageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(70).active=true
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought at first (which is why I changed the UIImageView to a brown background with MenuImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown).  The UIImageView itself seems to be the right size and in the right place, it is when programmatically adding an image, that the actual image is aligned to the bottom of the UIImageView.  I've tried your suggestion (with a few changes for Swift 3.0) and the the actual image is still not centred within the view.